# Styling <p> tags within a border box?

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a page right now which has blocks of text set in border boxes, and the text within these is styled.

Basically, the main problem I'm having is that within the styled `<p>` tag containing the border styling, when I try to break the text into another paragraph, the text after the `</p>` jumps outside of the box. I've tried adding the `<p>` in all kinds of different places but it just won't do what I want, and I can't find any tutorials on how to add extra paras within a paragraph styled with a border. Sample code below... this box was easy because there is only a single short paragraph. The rest of the page has multiple paragraphs that all need to fall within the border box.

Can anyone please help?

```
<p style="border: solid 3px #4D545E; padding: 6px;">
  <strong style="color: #c01d21;">Book your Christmas party</strong>
  on any Monday-Thursday in November – and all your guests will receive a complimentary Sorbete al Cava cocktail.
  <br>
  <a style="text-transform: uppercase;line-height: 38px;text-align: center; " class="link" href="http://www.manchesterconfidential.co.uk/b.aspx?b=6980" target="_blank">
  <strong>Click to book a table</strong>
  </a>
  Or call <strong>#### ### ####</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi, you can't add <p> tag inside <p>. It is bad practice. Else you can add span or other element and make it block.

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle example that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are saying, i have mad a snippet code for you here so that you can check it out, if it suites what you want, you can use it or try to explain more about what you want.

```css
.wrapper{
  border: solid 3px #4D545E; padding: 6px;
  }

.center{
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p><strong style="color: #c01d21;">Book your Christmas party</strong> on any Monday-Thursday in November – and all your guests will receive a complimentary Sorbete al Cava cocktail.</p>
<p class="center">
<a style="text-transform: uppercase;line-height: 38px;text-align: center; "class="link" href="http://www.manchesterconfidential.co.uk/b.aspx?b=6980" target="_blank"><strong>Click to book a table</strong></a></p>
<P class="center">
Or call <strong>#### ### ####</strong></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can I add images on here?

Comment: Yes you can add images na.

Answer (score 0):

following up on Jerry's answer above, to add multiple paragraphs should be as simple as adding`<p>`tags (assuming this is what you are looking for).

code wise, it'll be (working off Jerry's solution)

```
.wrapper{
  border: solid 3px #4D545E; padding: 6px;
}

.center{
  text-align:center;
 }
strong {
  color: #c01d21;
}
a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-algin: center;
}
```

I moved all your styling to CSS. And the html would be (same as above) + more `<p>` or any other tag you choose to add.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p><strong>Book your Christmas party</strong> on any Monday-Thursday in November – and   all your guests will receive a complimentary Sorbete al Cava cocktail.</p>
  <p class="center">
  <a class="link" href="http://www.manchesterconfidential.co.uk/b.aspx?b=6980" target="_blank"><strong>Click to book a table</strong></a></p>
  <P class="center">Or call <strong>#### ### ####</strong></p>

  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>

  <p class="center"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>

  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>

</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm still really struggling. I've changed the code according to the help that was posted yesterday, but now the grey box around each block of text isn't showing...

Comment: And I can't post the whole page code in here - it says it's too long

Comment: @MikeB - by not showing, you mean the border has disappeared? And can you post part of what your code looks like now? Not the whole page, just part of the CSS and HTML, this might give us a better idea. - Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
p.one {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

---

```
<p class="one">Some text.</p>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I'm really up against it here and I don't always get chance to jump back on and reply. There is an intern here at the moment who can answer some of my HTML questions, but thank you all for your input. No doubt I'll have more questions soon... :)